How to fix SwiftUI search bar glitchy animation?
Below is a sample code snippet demonstrating what I'm attempting to achieve. It's a basic list search that displays a static message when no results are found. However, the animation appears somewhat wonky. The view below momentarily jumps and overlaps the search bar for an instant. How can I make the animation smoother?

struct ContentView: View {
  let allStrings = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Elderberry", "Fig", "Grape", "Honeydew"]
  @State private var searchText = ""
  @State private var filteredStrings: [String] = []
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      rootView
        .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "Search")
    }
  }
  
  private var rootView: some View {
    List(filteredStrings, id: \.self) { string in
      Text(string)
    }
    .onChange(of: searchText) {
      filterStrings(with: searchText)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Fruits")
    .overlay {
      if filteredStrings.isEmpty {
        VStack {
          ContentUnavailableView("No recent searches",
                                 systemImage: "rectangle.and.text.magnifyingglass",
                                 description: Text("Your recent searches will appear here")).frame(width: 350, height: 200)
          Spacer()
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func filterStrings(with filter: String) {
    if filter.isEmpty {
      filteredStrings = []
    } else {
      filteredStrings = allStrings.filter { $0.contains(filter) }
    }
  }
}


Use explicit animations: Instead of relying on implicit animations, try using explicit animations with the .animation() modifier. This gives you more control over the animation and can sometimes help fix glitches.
You can simple add .animation to VStack like this:
...
.overlay {
    if filteredStrings.isEmpty {
        VStack {
            ContentUnavailableView("No recent searches",
                                   systemImage: "rectangle.and.text.magnifyingglass",
                                   description: Text("Your recent searches will appear here")).frame(width: 350, height: 200)
            Spacer()
        }
        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) //<- here
    }
}

Output


Thanks for the answer. But .animation is deprecated now. The new .animation needs a Boolean flag as well. Do we really need to manually animate this? If I use a List, animation is fine.

I've tried the new one, animation(_:value) with @Environment(\.isSearching) but didn't get the same result. I guess this is one of the limitations of SwiftUI. we must work around it. There were some issues before, not about this specific .searchable but this, someone already sent a report to Apple, hope they will improve in the future.
